# Prove that $\mathrm{fin}(^*\mathbb Q)/\mathrm{inf}(^*\mathbb Q)$ is complete.

Tags: real-numbers, nonstandard-analysis

I am trying to prove the existence of a standard map for $\overline{\mathbb Q}=\mathrm{fin}(^*\mathbb Q)/\mathrm{inf}(^*\mathbb Q)$ with $\mathrm{fin}(^*\mathbb Q)$ the set of finite numbers of $^*\mathbb Q$ and $\mathrm{inf}(^*\mathbb Q)$ the set of its infinitesimal numbers.

In other words, I am trying to prove that $\forall y\in\mathrm{fin}(^*\overline{\mathbb Q}),\exists x\in\overline{\mathbb Q},y\sim\ ^*x$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284282/why-mathrmfin-mathbb-q-mathrminf-mathbb-q-is-complete-using-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most straighforward proof is to use the isomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ with $\mathbb R$ obtained by sending an element of fin$({}^\ast\mathbb Q)$ to its standard part, which is an element of $\mathbb R$. Elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ differing by an infinitesimal in inf$({}^\ast\mathbb Q)$ obviously have the same standard part and therefore the isomorphism is well-defined.

Comment: I am trying to prove that $\text{fin}(^*\mathbb Q)/\text{inf}(^*\mathbb Q)$ is $\mathbb R$, without using usual constructions by Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences... :-(

Comment: You can use unending decimal expansions instead.  Just note that for each string of digits labeled by the natural numbers, there is a hyperrational with that initial string.